# Retrieve the second element of array for each document - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection, called `bios`, that contains documents similar to these:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51df07b094c6acd67e492f41"),
        "name" : {
                "first" : "John",
                "last" : "McCarthy"
        },
        "birth" : ISODate("1927-09-04T04:00:00Z"),
        "death" : ISODate("2011-12-24T05:00:00Z"),
        "contribs" : [
                "Lisp",
                "Artificial Intelligence",
                "ALGOL"
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : {
                "first" : "Grace",
                "last" : "Hopper"
        },
        "title" : "Rear Admiral",
        "birth" : ISODate("1906-12-09T05:00:00Z"),
        "death" : ISODate("1992-01-01T05:00:00Z"),
        "contribs" : [
                "UNIVAC",
                "compiler",
                "FLOW-MATIC",
                "COBOL"
        ]
}
```

My target is to retrieve the second element of the array contribs for each document in `bios` collection.
Using the new aggregation pipeline operator [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) I run the following query:

```
> db.bios.aggregate([
                     {
                      $match: {"contribs.2":{"$exists":1}}},
                     {
                      $project:{contribs:
                      {
                       $filter:{input:"$contribs", as: "contribs", cond:{}}},_id:0}}])
```

With my query, the output is:

```
{ "contribs" : [ "Lisp", "Artificial Intelligence", "ALGOL" ] }
{ "contribs" : [ "UNIVAC", "compiler", "FLOW-MATIC", "COBOL" ] }
```

that is not just the second element of the array `contribs` but a projection on `contribs` array when its second element exists.

Comment: Using `.aggregate()` is probably overkill here. Using `db.bios.find({ "contribs.1": { "$exists": true } },{ "contribs.$": 1 })` will return the matched element. The `"contribs"` returned would still be an array, but it will only be a single element, so that is easy to reference in code. The [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator would return as a single value, but unless you are continuing the aggregation pipeline after that result, then it should not be necessary. Nor the most performant approach.

Answer (score 6):

did you try $elementAt ?

```
db.bios.aggregate([
  { $match: {"contribs.1": { "$exists": 1 } }},
  { $project: { contribs: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$contribs", 1 ] } } }
]);
```